# Why is DrawRectangle drawing a cross inside my PictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, multidimensional-array, drawrectangle

I'm trying to draw 10 rectangles, but when I use `g.DrawRectangle()` it is drawing a cross as shown below:

[image: Drawing cross]

I'm creating Vertex objects that contain a getRectangle() function which returns a `Rectangle` object for that vertex.

I was hoping to create these objects and show them as Rectangles on the `pictureBox`.

*Here's my code*

```
    private System.Drawing.Graphics g;
    private System.Drawing.Pen pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 2F);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pictureBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void paintPictureBox(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the vertex on the screen
        g = e.Graphics;

        // Create new graph object
        Graph newGraph = new Graph();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
           // Tried this code too, but it still shows the cross
           //g.DrawRectangle(pen1, Rectangle(10,10,10,10);

           g.DrawRectangle(pen1, newGraph.verteces[0,i].getRectangle());
        }
    }
```

*Code for Vertex class*

```
class Vertex
{
    public int locationX;
    public int locationY;
    public int height = 10;
    public int width = 10;

    // Empty overload constructor
    public Vertex()
    {
    }

    // Constructor for Vertex
    public Vertex(int locX, int locY)
    {
        // Set the variables
        this.locationX = locX;
        this.locationY = locY;
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        // Create a rectangle out of the vertex information
        return new Rectangle(locationX, locationY, width, height);

    }
}
```

*Code for Graph class*

```
class Graph
{
    //verteces;
    public Vertex[,] verteces = new Vertex[10, 10];

    public Graph()
    {

        // Generate the graph, create the vertexs
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            // Create 10 Vertexes with different coordinates
            verteces[0, i] = new Vertex(0, i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: All i know is that some exception occurred whether in your code or in theirs. Try to remove some logic until you draw something, in order to debug the issue

Comment: As others have mentioned, the "cross" is a result of an exception being thrown. There's probably a bug in your code that would be easily to locate and fix if you weren't swallowing exceptions higher up the stack. There's an important lesson here after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an exception in your draw loop

last call to:

```
newGraph.verteces[0,i]
```

fails with `OutOfRangeException`
you shoul iterate not to `i <= 10`, but to `i < 10`

Comment: Even if I remove the `for` loop, and put just `g.DrawRectangle(pen1, newGraph.verteces[0, 1].getRectangle());` it still shows the cross :(

Comment: and if I put `g.DrawRectangle(pen1, new Rectangle(10,10,10,10));`

Comment: fix both loops. One in Graph constructor and one in paintPictureBox method

Comment: Yes, because you have above Graph newGraph = new Graph(); and that brakes your code

Comment: I've fixed both of the loops... I was baffled.  It now works, thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 2):

Red Cross Indicates that an Exception has been thrown, you are not seeing it because it's being handled. [Configure Visual Studio to break on exception throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

An exception has been thrown. At first look your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

will generate an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because `verteces` has 10 items but it will cycle from 0 to 10 (included so it'll search for 11 elements). It depends on what you want to do but you have to change the cycle to (removing the `=` from `<=`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

or to increment the size of `verteces` to 11.